# После Scanner.close() как работать со scanner?

Tags: java, scanner

Подскажите, закрыл `Scanner` методом `close()`. Потом как его открыть? Либо вообще не закрывать?

```
package n4;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class n4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double inputY,inputZ;
        boolean numberCorrect = false;

        Scanner in = null;
        in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Введите число double: ");
        inputY = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Было задано число: "+inputY);
        in.close();

        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Задайте еще одно значение типа double:");

        inputZ = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Было задано число: "+inputZ);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если закрыли, то придётся открывать новый.

Comment: А для чего закрывают его вообще?

Comment: Чтобы освободить ресурсы.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev какие ресурсы вы таким образом пытаетесь освободить? :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov конкретно в этом случае никакие. Но это не значит, что закрытием надо пренебрегать. Всё, что было открыто, должно быть закрыто.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev но в данном случае вы ничего не открывали. Потому и закрывать не надо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сам `Scanner` не является ресурсом, требующим освобождения, таковым является `InputStream` переданный в него. Если вы передаете `System.in`, то закрывать его не нужно, если передаете какой-то `InputStream`, связанный с файлом, сетевым ресурсом и т.п., то нужно закрывать.
Переоткрыть закрытый Scanner соответственно не получится, потому что закрывается непосредсвенно stream.

Comment: А есть ли ограничения на то как назвать Scanner ? Пытался тут давать что то отличное от in - не получалось.

Comment: @batqr, нет конечно, это же обычная переменная. Как хотите так и называйте в рамках правил именования переменных. Что-то вы не то пытались делать мне кажется.