# Как убрать лишнюю пустую строку после добавления System.lineSeparator()?

Tags: java, строки

```java
public void write() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    StringBuilder newContent = new StringBuilder();
    String userClipboard = getUserClipboard();
        
    copyToClipboard(myFileContent);
        
    System.out.println("Enter content or edit old (paste it). To stop writing, enter \"quitprogram\":");
    String line;

    while (!(line = scan.nextLine()).equals("quitprogram")) {
        newContent.append(line).append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
        
    scan.close();
        
    copyToClipboard(userClipboard);

    notepad.writeContent(newContent.toString());
    System.out.printf("Successfully written!\n\nWritten content:\n%s", newContent);
}
```

Ошибка заключается в том, что из-за `System.lineSeparator()` после ввода всего текста создается пустая новая строка в конце, чего я бы не хотел видеть.
Но как это исправить, если `System.lineSeparator()` мне нужен для разделения строк?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если использовать `StringBuilder` как в начальном коде, то по большому счёту имеется два варианта:

1. Удалить последний записанный перевод строки *после цикла* при помощи `StringBuilder::delete(int start, int end)`:

```java
String line;
StringBuilder newContent = new StringBuilder();
while (!"quitprogram".equals(line = scan.nextLine())) {
    newContent.append(line).append(System.lineSeparator());
}
newContent.delete(newContent.length() - System.lineSeparator().length(), newContent.length());
```

или просто уменьшить длину:

```java
//...
newContent.setLength(newContent.length() - System.lineSeparator().length());
```

2. Добавлять перевод строки *внутри цикла* только если `newContent` не является пустым:

```java
String line;
StringBuilder newContent = new StringBuilder();
while (!"quitprogram".equals(line = scan.nextLine())) {
    newContent
        .append(newContent.length() > 0 ? System.lineSeparator() : "")
        .append(line);
}
```

---

Альтернативное решение: вместо `StringBuilder` использовать [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) и его методы `StringJoiner::add`, `StringJoiner::toString`, что позволит избавиться от "ручного" управления соединением строк:

```java
String line;
StringJoiner newContent = new StringJoiner(System.lineSeparator());
while (!"quitprogram".equals(line = scan.nextLine())) {
    newContent.add(line);
}
// ...
notepad.writeContent(newContent.toString());
```

---

Также хотелось бы отметить, что НЕ нужно вызывать метод `scan.close()` для экземпляра сканера, открытого на системном потоке ввода `System.in`, так как это приведёт к закрытию самого потока `System.in`, и следовательно дальнейшая обработка ввода из консоли станет невозможна (см. [После `Scanner.close()` как работать со `scanner`?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/721901/))